# getting different values, by condition becoming more specific

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I have two pieces of code

```
SELECT * FROM etel.ti18n_country
                  inner join etel.ti18n
                  ON id_i18nid = i18nid WHERE id_countryid = 1
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM etel.ti18n_country
                  inner join etel.ti18n
                  ON id_i18nid = i18nid WHERE id_countryid = 1 and id_i18nid = 4460;
```

the first results in a bunch of results, but noticably none with id_i18nid = 4460

the second, however gets the result with id_i18nid = 4460.

how can that be? As I understand mysql the first piece of code should've had a result id_i18nid = 4460 for it to be possible for the second piece to have it aswell. Since I made the where clause more specific

Comment: Without providing a proper schema or properly qualifying your column names, it's a little difficult to follow.

Comment: which data type is the column id_i18nid ??  and  i18nid  ??

Comment: It can not. Do you execute this query in some shell like phpmyadmin? or any other which could automatically apply some `LIMIT`s? how many records are you getting back with 1st query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I was using Datagrips' ordering to find my id. since I had more than 500 results, datagrip takes random results and orders those. by ending the statement with `ORDER BY id_i18nid DESC` I found the result.